# How to update field in Mongo DB?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoose

I have document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("591ed2f0470e6ccc143c986e"),
    "name" : "Planets",
    "prototype_id" : null,
    "parameters" : [
        "591eefe3470e6cd70c3c9872",
        "591eefc3470e6c500f3c9872",
        "591eedbe470e6cd70c3c9871"
    ],
    "available" : "1"
}
```

I tried to set `[]` for field `parameters` if value `591eefe3470e6cd70c3c9872` exists in this array.

I tried:

```
$new = array('$set' => array("parameters" => []));

$this->collection->update(array("parameters" => "591eedbe470e6cd70c3c9871"), $new);
```

It does not work...

Comment: Sorry, I dont need remove all, I need pull out this element from array

Comment: Are you trying to set the array to [] when the query finds the input element in array ? or trying to pull the matching one out of the array ? Something like `$this->collection->update(array(), array('$pull' => array("parameters" => "591eedbe470e6cd70c3c9871"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's update() and save() methods are used to update document into a collection. The update() method updates the values in the existing document while the save() method replaces the existing document with the document passed in save() method.

**MongoDB Update() Method**

The update() method updates the values in the existing document.

**Syntax**

The basic syntax of update() method is as follows −

> db.COLLECTION_NAME.update(SELECTION_CRITERIA, UPDATED_DATA)

Consider the mycol collection has the following data

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec5), "title":"MongoDB Overview"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec6), "title":"NoSQL Overview"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec7), "title":"My Overview"}
```

Following example will set the new title 'New MongoDB Tutorial' of the documents whose title is 'MongoDB Overview'.

```
db.mycol.update({'title':'MongoDB Overview'},{$set:{'title':'New MongoDB Tutorial'}})
db.mycol.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec5), "title":"New MongoDB Tutorial"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec6), "title":"NoSQL Overview"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId(5983548781331adf45ec7), "title":"My Overview"}
```

By default, MongoDB will update only a single document. To update multiple documents, you need to set a parameter 'multi' to true.

```
db.mycol.update({'title':'MongoDB Overview'},
   {$set:{'title':'New MongoDB Tutorial'}},{multi:true})
```